# Is it possible to pass the FormArray index in [dateClass]?

Tags: angular, datepicker, formarray

I am tasked with a side-project in Angular (that I know almost nothing about). I want to create a multiple-date picker and I managed following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32fsyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts) to be able to click and save multiple dates per index in array.

My problem is about selected dates appearing.

```
  isSelected(event: any, i:any) {
    let tmp = new Date(event)
    const date = tmp.getFullYear() + "-" + ("00" + (tmp.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("00" + tmp.getDate()).slice(-2);
    let cur = this.routeDetailArray.at(i).get('routeDays').value
    if (cur==null) {return null} 
    else { return cur.find( x => x == date) ? "selected": null};
  };
```

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <mat-calendar #calendar 
            (selectedChange)="select($event,calendar,i)"
            [dateClass]="isSelected">
        </mat-calendar>
    </div>
</mat-menu>
```

I want to pass i inside 'IsSelected', however if I attempt to do this in HTML then I won't be receiving any correct dates. Currently I get the error: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'at')'. Obviously that is because it cannot read the index of the FormArray I working in.

I searched and found nothing relevant, probably my lack of knowledge led me to a serious slip, but I am that close into wrapping it up, it is about to drive me insane. Any ideas?

I tried [dateClass]='isSelected($event, i)' but that leads to other issues such as not receiving any proper dates based on the calendar.